# elisp libxml-parse-html-region return NIL

Tags: elisp

```
Here my elisp code (test by url "http://httpbin.org/html")

   (with-current-buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously my-url)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (re-search-forward "^$")
    (delete-region (point) (point-min))
    (setq dom (libxml-parse-html-region (point-min) (point-max)))
    (hoge--log-trace "Current buffer content: %s" (buffer-string))
    (hoge--log-trace "DOM is: %s" dom)
    )

To parse html I use elisp function "libxml-parse-html-region"

The result is:

Current buffer content: 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Herman Melville - Moby-Dick</h1>

      <div>
        <p>
          Availing himself ...
        </p>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
DOM is: nil
```

As you can see the buffer has content, but elisp function **libxml-parse-html-region** return nill and as result DOM object is NIL. Why?

Comment: Works just fine for me, with emacs 25.1.2.

Comment: my emacs is 25.1.2

Comment: Also works fine for me with version 24.4.1. (My 25.3 is configured without libxml2.) Perhaps the DOCTYPE annotation screws your setup, try `forward-line` after `delete-region`.